# Which version of Mac OS X included temporary exception entitlements for the first time?

Tags: macos, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I understand that sandbox was introduced in Mac OS X Lion (10.7) but temporary exception entitlements, specifically com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write, were introduced in a later 10.7.x update. Which 10.7.x update?

Comment: Why did you post the same question twice (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315072/timeline-for-mac-sandbox-entitlements-and-related-features)?

Answer (score 2):

its 10.7.2

[Check in this blog link](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2011/09/)